# Rendering a facebook like button with top.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a dynamic fb-like button that gets the page location but I'm looking for the best practices for replacing the data-href element of html:

I have two pieces of the puzzle:

1. `<div class="fb-like" data-href='' data-send="true"  data-colorscheme="dark" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`
2. top.location.href

Which js method would allow top.location.href to replace data-href element, AND render the facebook like button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you normally would?

```
document.getElementById("the_like_button").setAttribute("data-href", new_value);
```

or:

```
$("#the_like_button").attr("data-href", new_value);
```

If you prefer jQuery.